# Override not working on onNewTask() in FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've just installed Firebase in my Android app to enable push notifications. I confirmed it's working by sending a push notification from the Firebase console to all devices running the app. Now I'm trying to get the FCM token (the unique identifier of the app instance) so I can send messages to specific devices. However, when I override the onNewToken() function in my class extending the FirebaseMessagingService, the method is not overridden. [According to the docs it should work](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService#onNewToken(java.lang.String)). The other methods in the doc are successfully overridden. I've found and decompiled the FirebaseMessagingService class file in my external libraries, and found out that the onNewToken function is indeed not present there.

How can I override a function that should exist according to the docs, but doesn't exist in the class file?

I'm using com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0 and com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because, as you comment before, Firebase Instance ID is deprecated but it refers to the complet class, then you should use @Override ... onNewToken in a different class, not in Firebase Instance Id class .Sorry for my english.  The example is this:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

   @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
    Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s);
}
```